# Возможно ли подключить к БД postres внешнюю таблицу?

Tags: postgresql

Здравствуйте, скажите возможно ли подключить к одной базе postgres таблицу из другой базы postgres, которая находится на другой машине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу сходу дать две возможности:

старый и известный модуль [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), добавляющий процедуры подключения к другому серверу (или даже тому же самому) и выполнения SQL-запросов.

активно сейчас развиваемый механизм [FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html). [Вики](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). Это возможность объявить таблицу как локальную, но реально она находится в другом месте. При этом, с этой таблицей можно выполнять join и другие махинации как будто она локальная. В 9.1 появилась возможность только читать, в 9.3 - чтение и запись. Сейчас активно пилится в сторону оптимальности выполнения запросов - например, попросить удалённую машину саму построить группировку, а не вычитывать всё к себе и агрегировать локально.